Type-safe table in TypeScript
While writing code for a particular client, I needed a table to represent some of the data. Here's the loosely typed version of the table I want to use:
class Table {
  private rowStorage: unknown[][] = [];
  private rowDefinition: string[];
  constructor(rowDefinition: string[]) {
    this.rowDefinition = rowDefinition;
  }

  getFromReference(
    referenceColumn: string,
    value: unknown,
    desiredColumn: string,
  ) {
    return this.rowStorage.find(
      (row) => row[this.rowDefinition.indexOf(referenceColumn)] === value,
    )![this.rowDefinition.indexOf(desiredColumn)];
  }

  addRow(toAdd: unknown[]) {
    this.rowStorage.push(toAdd);
  }
}

I have reasons for representing each row and the table as arrays. The value passed to the constructor is an array representing the name of each column. Those names are later used to reference the column in question.
I have quite a few requirements for this table, but I don't even know if they're possible. That's why I'm reaching out to this community. If not, even if you guys can find a way to achieve this task, then I'll open an issue on TypeScript's repo requesting features that would allow us to solve this problem. Therefore, even if you cannot solve it, try to think of what could be added to TypeScript itself to help with this.
Also, if you know of any language in which this problem can be solved, I'd be glad to expand my horizons.
Here it goes, I would like to pass a list of types representing the type of each column on the table. For example, let's assume a table that receives ['name', 'age'] in its constructor. The list of types should also take two types, for example: <string, number> or <[string, number]>The catch is that I want a type error if the type list and the list of strings have different lengths.
One thing to note here is that the list of strings will most likely never take anything that isn't literal.
My following requirement is for the getFromReference method. The second argument should expect the correct type for the column passed on the first argument. The final return value should also have the correct type for the column passed as the third argument.

You'll have a much easier time using objects, at least for the types: Table<T extends Record<string, unknown>> or Table<K extends string, T extends Record<K, unknown>>. If it's absolutely necessary to use arrays, you can probably still do with Table<Cols extends string[], T extends Record<Cols[number], unknown>> and a mapped tuple type { [Index in keyof Cols]: T[Cols[Index]] } for the rows.

In either case, the lookup method would be typed as getFromReference<Rk extends keyof T, Dk extends keyof T>(referenceColumn: Rk, value: T[Rk], desiredColumn: Dk): T[Dk]

Welcome to Stack Overflow. TypeScript can model just about all of this stuff but getting the compiler to actually follow such logic is beyond its abilities and not something I'd recommend adding a feature request for.  Maybe this approach is what you're looking for?  If so let me know and I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

If I correctly understand what you are trying to do, it can be achieved using tuples.
class Table<RowStorageType extends [...unknown[]]> {
  private rowStorage: RowStorageType[] = [];
  private rowDefinition: string[];

  constructor(rowDefinition: string[]) {
    this.rowDefinition = rowDefinition;
  }

  getFromReference(
    referenceColumn: string,
    value: unknown,
    desiredColumn: string,
  ) {
    const foundValue = this.rowStorage.find(
      (row) => row[this.rowDefinition.indexOf(referenceColumn)] === value,
    );
    
    if (!foundValue) {
        console.log('not found');
        return [this.rowDefinition.indexOf(desiredColumn)]
    }
    
    return foundValue;
  }

  addRow(toAdd: RowStorageType) {
    this.rowStorage.push(toAdd);
  }
}

It is the instanciated and called with with
const t = new Table<[string, number]>(['name', 'age']);
t.addRow(['john', 25]);

You can experiment with that suggestion on this playground.
To elaborate on the proposed solution, type [...[]] is a tuple with any number of members, all of type unknown. So you declare Table.rowStorage as being an array of RowStorageType, where RowStorageType has to be a tuple that can be defined when instanciating the class by using templates. Not respecting the template type will raise a type error at build time or when running a tool such as eslint, but will not be an issue at runtime (if you bypass the type checking with a cast to any for example) if the type are compatible.
